# Glimpse Heads Up Display is not showing up when debugging in VS 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, glimpse

I installed Glimpse in my Web project that is using MVC5 via Nuget. I am using Visual Studio 2017 with Resharper. I also am running through IIS so it is giving me back app.company.local rather than using IIS Express and localhost. Could that be the problem?

I have gone through the troubleshooting documentation as well as quite a few questions on here but Glimpse's HUD is not showing up for some reason.

Below are some if not all of the changes made to try and get it to work.

```
packages.config
  <package id="Glimpse" version="1.8.6" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Glimpse.Ado" version="1.7.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Glimpse.AspNet" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Glimpse.EF6" version="1.6.5" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Glimpse.Mvc5" version="1.5.3" targetFramework="net461" />

index.cshtml
  added @using Glimpse.Mvc.Html to the top and @Html.GlimpseClient() to the bottom
  (there are a bunch of divs and no body tag)

Web.config
  <add key="Glimpse:DisableAsyncSupport" value="true" />
  <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" /></httpModules>
  <add path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" />
  <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" /></modules>
  <add name="Glimpse" path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" /></handlers>
  <glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
  <add type="Glimpse.Mvc.Inspector.DependencyInjectionInspector, Glimpse.Mvc5" />
 <add type="Glimpse.AspNet.Policy.LocalPolicy, Glimpse.AspNet"/>
```

What do I need to do in order to get this to work/show up?

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem for company.local.

You would just need to go to:

```
app.company.local/Glimpse.axd
```

To get to you config display. Then

You have not enabled Glimpse in the **web.config**, by setting **defaultRuntimePolicy** to **On**:

```
<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
...
</glimpse>
```